# MongoDB object - PYTHON

Tags: python, mongodb, web-services, web, database

I am doing an web app and i have a dude. I need to get a value of a MongoDb JSON? object. I post my code..

```
import pymongo

try:
   conn =pymongo.MongoClient('localhost')
   print('Conexion realizada:')
except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure, e:
    print('No se ha podido realizar la conexion: %s' % e)
db = conn.test 
coll = db.puntos 
print(list(coll.oxigeno.find())) <-- I want to print the Oxigeno value of the Object
```

Thanks you so much

Comment: is `oxigeno` a key of `db.puntos`?

Comment: yes, i copy you the output of that code [{u'cordenadas': {u'y': 4.0, u'x': 2.0}, u'oxigeno': 2.0, u'_id': ObjectId('54565b6d631732a913ea985d')}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a list of the `find` return object, and accessing their keys by list comprehension like this:

```
print [each['oxigeno'] for each in coll.find()]
```

You may think of the `find` return object as a list of dictionary/ies. So basically you just need to iterate the list and access the values in each dictionary.